# Drop down menus in list HTML

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been answered in several threads , but this is different.

I am doing the drop down on hover using css and everything is working fine :
here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/2UJDe/

Since , the code dropdown is not appearing fine as expected , i added some code and here is the resulting code : http://jsfiddle.net/geJmF/   ( i have added id to individual list to just fix the dropdown positions )
  But somehow now the things are not working.

Anyone any idea ??

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected result.

Comment: Could you show us a picture of what you want to achieve? Some things seem pretty unnecessary. Could seem like you forgot a position: relative;?

Comment: I want the dropdown to appear below the correspond menu item. As u can see the first code open the dropdown overlapping over the main menu.

Comment: position:relative is not necessary as i have calculated the absolute positions. It didnt work as well. What i noticied is if i change the top value for dropdown items to fall within the bounds of main menu , it start to appear but similar as before. : http://jsfiddle.net/jvKRN/

Answer (score 0):

Change the float property to right:

```
#navbar_2 li a
{
    background : #878787;
    color : white;
    float : right;
```

And changing some heights and widths, Menu 2 tab looks as: http://jsfiddle.net/jvKRN/35/

CSS here:

```
#navbar_2
{
    height : 200px;
    left : 140px;
    overflow : hidden;
    position : absolute;
    top : 70px;
    width : 800px;
    display : inline-table;
    list-style : none;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    table-layout : fixed;

}

#navbar_2 li
{
    background-color : #878787;
    display : table-cell;

}

#navbar_2 li a
{
    background : #878787;
    color : white;
    float : right;
    font-family : Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size : 32px;
    height : 100.000%;
    line-height : 200px;
    padding : 0px 0;
    text-align : center;
    text-decoration : none;
    white-space : nowrap;
    width : 100%;

    border-left : 1px solid black;
}

#navbar_2 li a:hover
{
    background : black;
     color : white;

}

#navbar_2 li:hover ul
{
    left: auto;

}

#navbar_2 li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: -999em;

}

#navbar_2_1
{
    display : inline;
    height : 600px;
    list-style : none;
    overflow : hidden;
    position : absolute;
    table-layout : auto;
    top : 200px;
    width : 200px;

}
#navbar_2_2
{
    display : inline;
    height : 600px;
       list-style : none;
    margin : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
    padding : 0;
    position : absolute;
    table-layout : auto;
    top : 200px;
    width : 200px;

}

#navbar_2_3
{
    display : inline;
    height : 600px;
    left : 740px;
    list-style : none;
    margin : 0;
    overflow : hidden;
    padding : 0;
    position : absolute;
    table-layout : auto;
    top : 200px;
    width : 200px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things incorrect.

I'm not sure why you are using table-cell display properties, they are not needed and probably are hindering your display.

Secondly, because we are dealing with multiple levels of navigation which behave differently, we need to be able to target/limit our styles. In this case I've used the child select ( > ) in my styles to do this.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nb4zU/